# Value of instantaneous variable is not assigned same as passed to Constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am doing a problem related to Insertion Sort (this is not my problem) but i am having the following problem.

(Problem starts here)
I create a constructor where is am passing 5 to size variable.
But when in Constructor after assignment i `cout<<this->size;` it displays 1 but i am expecting 5

```
class InsertionSort{
    public:
        int array[];
        int size;
        InsertionSort(int *array, int size);
        void sort();
        void displayArray();
};

InsertionSort::InsertionSort(int array[], int size){
    this->array[size];
    this->size= size;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        this->array[i]= array[i];
    }
    //here is the cout
    cout<<"size "<<size<<endl;
    cout<<"This->size "<<this->size<<endl;
}
```

I am expecting 
`size 5
This->size 5`
but it is giving 
`size 5
This->size 1`
You can check my `main()` function:

`main() {
    int arr[]= {1,5,4,8,3};
    InsertionSort a(&arr[0], 5);
}`

When i create object with these values:

`InsertionSort a(&arr[1], 5);`

value of assigned to `this->size` becomes 5 i-e value at `arr[1]`

Please correct me where i am doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you think `this->array[size]` does? (hint: nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defining

```
int array[];
```

inside of a class should be at the end of the class definition unless you're setting a fixed size
if you want it to a dynamic size, use dynamic allocation by declaring it like

```
int *array;
```

and in the constructor, use

```
this->array = new int[size];
```

as for the line

```
this->array[size];
```

it has no meaning..

Comment: Note that `int array[];` as a data member isn't valid C++.

Comment: @RizwanAmjad It isn't clear that you need to `new` the array in the class either. You will be essentially making a copy (and introducing a memory leak.) Do you need to copy an array to sort it?

Comment: Yes I was trying to copy the array as a data member. But that was the real mistake. Now my issue is solved. I am using dynamic allocation for `array` using `new` keyword. Thanks to everyone who helped me in this problem :)